# A necessary and sufficient condition on the matrices for a particular implication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$.

I'm looking for a (necessary and) sufficient condition on the matrices $A,B,C$ and $D$ such that
\begin{align}
 x &= A x + B u, \\
 y &= C x + D u, 
\end{align}
implies
\begin{gather}
 \sum_{i=1}^{m} u_i = 0, \\
 y_1 = \ldots = y_{m}, 
\end{gather}
where
$x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $y,u\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

---

In my specific application in all examples this holds, and is exactly what we require for the example to make sense/to be of any value. Thus, if I'm able to find a sufficient and necessary condition, that's hopefully easy to verify numerically, it will enable us to exclude "bad" examples immediately/in an automated fashion.

Comment: Some context is clearly needed here. Where is that problem coming from?

Comment: @KBS it has to do with fixed points of discrete-time systems (a linear time-invariant system in feedback interconnection with particular nonlinearities).

Comment: Do not delete a question immediately after you get an answer.  This is rude to the person who took the time to answer your question, and rude to potential future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Assume first that $A-I$ is invertible, then we have that $x=(I-A)^{-1}Bu$ and, therefore, $y=(C(I-A)^{-1}B+D)u$.

Now, we have that all the components of $y$ are the same if and only if $Z^Ty=0$ where $Z=\begin{bmatrix}e_1-e_2 & e_1-e_3 & \ldots & e_1-e_m\end{bmatrix}$ where $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is the natural basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Therefore, we need to have that $Z^T(C(I-A)^{-1}B+D)u=0$ together with $\mathbf{1}^Tu=0$. This can be expressed as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}Z^T(C(I-A)^{-1}B+D)\\\mathbf{1}^T\end{bmatrix}u=0.
$$

We look for nontrivial solutions $u$ and for them to exist we need the square matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}Z^T(C(I-A)^{-1}B+D)\\\mathbf{1}^T\end{bmatrix}
$$
to be singular.

When $A-I$ is singular and such that $B\in\mathrm{span}(I-A)$, then we have that

$$
x=(I-A)^+Bu+(I-(I-A)^+(I-A))v
$$

where the superscript $+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. We then get the condition

$$
\begin{bmatrix}Z^T(C(I-A)^{+}B+D)\\\mathbf{1}^T\end{bmatrix}u+\begin{bmatrix}Z^T(I-(I-A)^+(I-A))\\0\end{bmatrix}v=0.
$$

Now, it depends on the interpretation of the problem. Either the above expression is satisfied for some $v$ or for all $v$. In the former case, we can also divide the problem in two cases: $v$ is chosen or $v$ is given.

If $v$ is chosen, then we can just pick $v=0$ and we end up with checking the invertibility of

$$
\begin{bmatrix}Z^T(C(I-A)^{+}B+D)\\\mathbf{1}^T\end{bmatrix}.
$$

If $v\ne0$ is given, say $v=v_0$, then we need that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}Z^T(I-(I-A)^+(I-A))v_0\\0\end{bmatrix}\in\mathrm{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix}Z^T(C(I-A)^{+}B+D)\\\mathbf{1}^T\end{bmatrix}\right).
$$

Finally, if the expression needs to be satisfied for all $v$'s, then we have two possibilities: either $u$ can be chosen depending on the value for $v$ or $u$ needs to be same regardless the value of $v$.

In the former case, we need that

$$
\mathrm{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix}Z^T(I-(I-A)^+(I-A))\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)\subset\mathrm{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix}Z^T(C(I-A)^{+}B+D)\\\mathbf{1}^T\end{bmatrix}\right).
$$

In the latter case, we need to have $Z^T(I-(I-A)^+(I-A))=0$.

Comment: I sad fact is that $A-I$ is not invertible in all my examples (i.e., 10+ examples).

Comment: @sum_math This means that you have a continuum of fixed points for your dynamics. Are you sure that makes sense in your setting? Please update your question accordingly and mention all the necessary details.

Comment: Yes! We are working with classes of nonlinearities, and picking one specific nonlinearity will force uniqueness. All the necessary details are in the question.

Comment: @sum_math No, all the details are NOT in the question. Please update your question with the dynamical system part, the nonlinearities, etc. More context is definitely needed here.

Comment: I don't agree. Clearly, I can't look at a subset of the possible examples and check for structure in the matrices that generalises to all examples. What I know of a fact is that if I can find a necessary and sufficient condition for the above problem then my dynamical system problem is completely solved.

Comment: @sum_math What are you not agreeing with? Your question lacks important details on the context, whether you agree or not.